# Get empty lua file when decompiling the luac file

Tags: lua, decompiler

I'm trying to decompile some .luac files unzipped from a game.And I tried some tools (unLuac & Luadec) but all of them gave me an empty .lua file with 0kb.

Are these luac files encrypt or I just use the wrong version of tools?
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: There's a difference between LuaJIT and CLua bytecode, as well as Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2. Maybe your decompilers are for the wrong target.

Comment: So…is there anyway to get the right target by analyzing the .luac files?I can just see the string "NJ" in the messy code in every luac file.I don't know if it means something。

Answer (score -1):

The `.luac` can't do this, it's encrptyed.

Comment: If it is encrypted, I have to write some algorithm code to decrypt it first before decompile it, right?

Comment: "Encrypted" is the wrong word, it's just compiled source code to bytecode. Bytecode still can be read with the same functionality of the source to discover, just in another form.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! So it appears that the point is how to find out the right decompilers to read the bytecode.Is there any way to get the source compile tool (like LuaJit or CLua) ?